# Coroutinas y asyncio.Queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio

Estoy *experimentando* con [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/asyncio.html) (en python3.8). De entrada, una pequeña prueba de como usar [`asyncio.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/asyncio-queue.html); simplemente, colocar un dato en la cola y volver a obtenerlo.

```
import asyncio

class QServer:
    def _getQueue( self, queueName ):
        queue = self._queues.get( queueName )

        if queue is None:
            queue = asyncio.Queue( )
            self._queues[queueName] = asyncio.Queue( ) 

        return queue

    def __init__( self ):
        self._queues = { }

    async def put( self, queueName, data ):
        queue = self._getQueue( queueName )
        await queue.put( data )

    async def get( self, queueName ):
        queue = self._getQueue( queueName )
        return await queue.get( )

async def main( ):
    QueueName = 'TestQueue'
    TestData = 'TestData'

    queue = QServer( )

    print( 'put' )
    await queue.put( QueueName, TestData )
    internal = queue._getQueue( QueueName )
    print( internal.qsize( ) )
    print( 'type' )
    assert( type( queue._queues[ QueueName ] ) == type( asyncio.Queue( ) ) )
    print( 'get' )
    assert( await queue.get( QueueName ) == TestData )
    print( 'End' )

asyncio.run( main( ) )
```

La salida que yo esperaba es:

> put
> 1
> type
> get
> End

Sin embargo, estoy obteniendo esta otra:

> put
> 0
> type
> get

Y ahí el programa se queda a la espera indefinidamente, hasta que pulso <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> y lo finalizo.

A mis neófitos ojos, da la sensación de que `put( )` **no está** colocando ningún elemento en la cola. Y tengo la sospecha de que no estoy entendiendo correctamente el funcionamiento de las *coroutinas*.

- ¿ Qué estoy haciendo mal ?
- ¿ Cómo lo soluciono ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Te vas a tirar de los pelos cuando leas esto, pero... Tu comprensión de asyncio, corutinas y colas es correcta, sólo que tienes un bug aquí, dentro de `_getQueue()`:

```py
        if queue is None:
            queue = asyncio.Queue( )
            self._queues[queueName] = asyncio.Queue( ) 
        return queue
```

Como ves, creas una cola nueva, que asignas a la variable `queue`, y que es la que finalmente retornas (y sobre la que se va a hacer el `put()`), pero *sin embargo* lo  que guardas en el diccionario `self._queues` no es esa cola que has creado, sino otra nueva diferente, pues llamas de nuevo a `asyncio.Queue()`. Debido a eso, la cola en la que después haces `get()`, que es la que se guarda en ese diccionario, es diferente de la que usaste para el `put()`.

En definitiva, ese trocito debería estar así:

```py
        if queue is None:
            queue = asyncio.Queue( )
            self._queues[queueName] = queue

        return queue
```

Con ese cambio, ahora sí, la salida es la que esperas:

```html
put
1
type
get
End
```

### Bonus

Si quieres, y si usas Python 3.8+, también puedes usar el operador de asignación (`:=`) que te permite ahorrar una línea, aunque sospecho que a costa de la legibilidad:

```py
        if queue is None:
            self._queues[queueName] = (queue := asyncio.Queue())

        return queue
```

Aunque ciertamente la opción más pythónica sería usar `defaultdict`, que es un tipo de diccionario que crea automáticamente nuevos elementos (del tipo que elijas al crear el diccionario) cuando le pides una clave que no existe.

Con este enfoque te ahorras la función `._getQueue()` completa y te quedaría así:

```py
import asyncio
from collections import defaultdict

class QServer:
    def __init__( self ):
        # A defaultdict se le pasa qué constructor usar para crear elementos nuevos
        self._queues = defaultdict(asyncio.Queue)

    async def put( self, queueName, data ):
        queue = self._queues[queueName]
        await queue.put( data )

    async def get( self, queueName ):
        queue = self._queues[queueName]
        return await queue.get( )

async def main( ):
    QueueName = 'TestQueue'
    TestData = 'TestData'

    queue = QServer( )

    print( 'put' )
    await queue.put( QueueName, TestData )
    internal = queue._queues[ QueueName ]
    print( internal.qsize( ) )
    print( 'type' )
    assert( type( queue._queues[ QueueName ] ) == type( asyncio.Queue( ) ) )
    print( 'get' )
    assert( await queue.get( QueueName ) == TestData )
    print( 'End' )

asyncio.run( main( ) )
```

Comment: `Te vas a tirar de los pelos cuando leas esto, pero... ` 

Comment: Esta linea `self._queues[queueName] = (queue := asyncio.Queue())` podrías cambiarla por esta `self._queues[queueName] = queue = asyncio.Queue()` y supongo que eso funciona en versiones inferiores de python, además de mantener la legibilidad.

Comment: @DanteS. Es verdad, cómo me he complicado inútilmente. Ha sido culpa del C, pues al pensar que en Python el operador de asignación es una sentencia y no una expresión (como en C), fui directamente al nuevo operador de asignación que sí es una expresión (el `:=`) sin darme cuenta de que python tiene también la asignación múltiple que indicas, como azúcar sintáctico.